# Qml : switch qml view

Tags: c++11, qml, qt5

I'm a beginner in QML.

I have a Loading.qml and a main.qml

I want to display the loading.qml at the application starting, and when all my data are ready, I want to hide the loading.qml and display the main.qml

I want to do that from c++ code

How can I do that ?

Thank you

[UPDATE]

I have tried this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   
   QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
   QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

   qmlRegisterType<MyWindow>("project.mywindow", 1, 0, "MyWindow");

   engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/LoadingPage.qml"));
   if(engine.rootObjects().isEmpty()) return -1;

   // simulate preloading data
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5)); 

   engine. ? -> switch to another view ?

   /*engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
   if(engine.rootObjects().isEmpty()) return -1;*/

   return app.exec();
}
```

My QML
LoadingPage.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
   id: loading
   visible: true
   width: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth
   height: Screen.desktopAvailableHeight
   title: qsTr("Board")

   Loader {
    id: pageLoader
   }

   Component.onCompleted: {
    pageLoader.source = "qrc:/main.qml"
    loading.visible = false
   }

   Image {
    id: logo
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    width: 100
    height: 100
    source: "qrc:/img/download.jpeg"
   }

   Button {
       id: btn
       width: 250
       height: 250
       x: 250
       y: 0
       onClicked: {
        pageLoader.source = "qrc:/main.qml"
        loading.visible = false
       }
   }
}
```

I want to when my main.qml is ready (when c++ construction of my class MyWindow) is ok, I want to switch to them.

Comment: first of all you have to provide your attempt to solve the issue. Please read how to provide [mcve]. If you have difficulties with QML as a beginner I can recommend the [QML book](https://qmlbook.github.io/)

Comment: @folibis thank you for the book. I have added a minimal example what is want to do.

Comment: You have [Component.completed](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#completed-signal) signal that will be fired when your object will be "ready". So you can use it to perform some action. As for doing that from C++ (especially adding delays in the main thread) I guess it's absolutely wrong approach.

Comment: @folibis I have updated my description

Comment: you should load data or whatever you do in a different thread. if you insert the delay between loading QML components and `app.exec()` you're taking the message loop out of the game and so you are in trouble.

Comment: btw, if your target is a splash screen you can use one of tens solutions that were asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=qml+splash+screen) or one from [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtquick-window-splash-qml.html)

Comment: @folibis In fact, in the MyWindow class, I have a thread that send GET request every X seconds.
I will externalize that : while my data are not ready, I will show the LoadingPage.qml and when my are ready, i will change to main.qml. What do you think about that solution ?